# Why can't I read php echo or printf from android app?

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to write on my android app just a small message from a php-file I have on my WAMP-server.

In my main activity I am only using a button to create a `AsyncTask` that should find the php-file and read the content of it and print it out in the form of a `Toast`- message.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@string/log_in"
    android:id="@+id/logInButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordText"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/registerText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/passwordText"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:onClick="LogIn" />
```

And the function in my main class

```
public void LogIn (View view){
    //String username = _userName.getText().toString();
    //String password = _password.getText().toString();
    BackgroundHandler bh = new BackgroundHandler(this);
    bh.execute();
    /*FetchPhp fp = new FetchPhp(this);
    String m = fp.GetTheFuckingEcho();
    Toast.makeText(this, m , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);*/
}
```

And here is Background handler that should fetch the php echo.

```
public class BackgroundHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context c;
AlertDialog alert;
String line , results;

public BackgroundHandler(Context c){this.c = c; }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
    try {
        String db_url = "http://192.168.1.210:8081/test.php";

        URL url = new URL(db_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpHandler = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpHandler.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpHandler.setDoInput(true);
        InputStream is = httpHandler.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        results = br.readLine();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("ErrorMessage", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(c, results, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   // alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(c).create();
   // alert.setTitle("TestTitle");
}

}
```

When I click on the button NOTHING happends. I've try with several different approaches and nothing is working. And I'm not receiving any error messages or problems. Nothing happends. And yes I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in my Manifest.xml-File. and I can access the php-file through my local and "distant" computers. I just can't seem to fetch the echo string.

And the php-file contains `<?php printf("test"); ?>`

**Edit here is the full MainActivity class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button _logIn;
    EditText _userName;
    EditText _password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logInButton);
        _userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        _password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        CheckForNTConnection();
    }

    public void LogIn (View view){
        //String username = _userName.getText().toString();
        //String password = _password.getText().toString();
        BackgroundHandler bh = new BackgroundHandler(this);
        bh.execute();

        /*FetchPhp fp = new FetchPhp(this);
        String m = fp.GetTheFuckingEcho();
        Toast.makeText(this, m , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);*/
    }
    //NT = Network
    public void CheckForNTConnection()
    {
        ConnectivityManager CM = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = CM.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(info != null && info.isConnected())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, info.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as pictures! Makes it difficult for us to be able to replicate and debug if they are pictures

Comment: Are you able to get the response from mobile web browser?

Comment: Yes @MadhukarHebbar

Comment: In Server, log each request to file and send the same request as the response.
Check the HTTP status code in the client ; Read the header from the response;

Comment: have you tried to change the context of the toast? because i see you declare it on "c" variable which is a context, try getapplicationcontext or get activity

Comment: use `int responseCode = httpHandler.getResponseCode();` in your `doInBackground` method to determine what error code you are getting. once you know what error is causing the crash you can search for the solutions.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez It doesn't show me anything. Not sure if I've used it correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logInButton);
    _userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
    _password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    CheckForNTConnection();
    LogIn();
}

public void LogIn (){

    BackgroundHandler bh = new BackgroundHandler(this);
    bh.execute();

}
//NT = Network
public void CheckForNTConnection()
{
    ConnectivityManager CM = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = CM.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(info != null && info.isConnected())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, info.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}

public class BackgroundHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context c;
AlertDialog alert;


public BackgroundHandler(Context c)
{this.c = c; 
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
    String line , results;
    try {
        String db_url = "http://192.168.1.210:8081/test.php";

        URL url = new URL(db_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpHandler = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpHandler.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpHandler.setDoInput(true);
        InputStream is = httpHandler.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        results = br.readLine();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("ErrorMessage", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return results;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //result is s
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   // alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(c).create();
   // alert.setTitle("TestTitle");
}

}
```

Comment: I can't use `getApplicationContext()` for some reason. Just gives me error.

Comment: Use the Context of class like: class_name.this.

Comment: Doesn't work with `BackgroundHandler.this.getApplicationContext()` or with `MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()`. It only works with `c.getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @Bojje Hey man one quick suggestion, don't go to fast on android learn the basics. What I mean is use the name of parent class and add `.this`. Context doesn't always mean `getApplicationContext()`. Use the name of parent class of `BackgroundHandler` and add `.this` after the name of class. like : `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Ah okey. Well I did it but I am still not receiving anything.

Comment: Added the MainActivity class.

Comment: @W410CK5 No I found it.. I just didn't put `.show()` at the end of the `Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`...
Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Just edit your answer with .show() then I can do it :)